# Navigation bar Background not showing color

Tags: ios, xcode, email, objective-c-blocks

I am using MFMailComposeViewController for sending mails.
I have cutomise set the navigation bar with blue color
But issue is that its working fine in my simulator and ipod 5 but color of navigation not showing in iphone 5

```
      [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Topbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [UIFont fontWithName:@"SinkinSans-400Regular" size:17],
      NSFontAttributeName,  [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
      [UIColor whiteColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil]];
```

Comment: You set first background image and then set color how can show both image or color?

Comment: So the image set to the background and then i am setting the text color for the navigation bar

Comment: your question is navigation background not showing color? right, then your navigation display only image not display color (white). because only show image other wise color not both display in background.

Comment: I have remove the setbackgroudimage method and its working fine in all screens. But when i use setbackgroundImage its showing image everywhere except MFMailComposeViewController. Don't know why this will happens